# Dropdown with checkboxes from inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm developing an asp.net website where i want to include in my html using asp a dropdwon menu with checkboxes and i want to know if these checkboxes are selected. if anyone can help me please ?

[image: and here's what i want to build :]

Comment: Your question is not more clearly. If you don't change, you get downvote, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use javascript/jQuery to prevent the dropdown from toggling when you click the checkboxes. Here is an example dropdown with checkboxes:

HTML:

```
<dl class="dropdown"> 

    <dt>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="hida">Select</span>    
      <p class="multiSel"></p>  
    </a>
    </dt>

    <dd>
        <div class="mutliSelect">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Apple" />Apple</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Blackberry" />Blackberry</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="HTC" />HTC</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Sony Ericson" />Sony Ericson</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Motorola" />Motorola</li>
                <li>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Nokia" />Nokia</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </dd>
  <button>Filter</button>
</dl>
```

CSS:

```
body {  
    font: normal 14px/100% "Andale Mono", AndaleMono, monospace;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #374954;

} 
a {
    color:#fff;
}
.dropdown dd, .dropdown dt {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
.dropdown ul {
    margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}
.dropdown dd {
    position:relative;
}
.dropdown a, 
.dropdown a:visited {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    outline:none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.dropdown dt a {
    background-color:#4F6877;
    display:block;
    padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
    min-height: 25px;
    line-height: 24px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:0;
    width:272px;
}
.dropdown dt a span, .multiSel span {
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 3px 2px 0;
}
.dropdown dd ul {
    background-color: #4F6877;
    border:0;
    color:#fff;
    display:none;
    left:0px;
    padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    width:280px;
    list-style:none;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.dropdown span.value {
    display:none;
}
.dropdown dd ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
}
.dropdown dd ul li a:hover {
    background-color:#fff;
}
button {
  background-color: #6BBE92;
  width: 302px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
          $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
      });

      $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
          $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
      });

      function getSelectedValue(id) {
           return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
      }

      $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
          var $clicked = $(e.target);
          if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
      });


      $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {

          var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
              title = $(this).val() + ",";

          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
              $('.multiSel').append(html);
              $(".hida").hide();
          } 
          else {
              $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
              var ret = $(".hida");
              $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

          }
});
```

Codepen with above codes: http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/hlmri

(Author attributes available in codepen)

Comment: You edited the question right after I wrote this answer -_-

Comment: i want to know how to access these checkboxes if they're selected in my default.aspx.cs

Answer (score 0):

**You Should**

- Make sure you assign Unique ID for each `checkbox elements`.

**By Using `JQuery`:**

`$('#' + id).is(":checked")`

Comment: i want to know how to access these checkboxes if they're selected in my default.aspx.cs  ??

Comment: Your question is about knowing if a `checkbox` is selected or not. Please explain what do you mean by accessing a `checkbox` ?

Comment: supposedly i have an array in javascript which contains the values for the selected checkboxes, so  i want to send this array to c# asp how to take it from javascript to asp in my default.aspx.cs file ?

Comment: You are taking the long way if you check for selected `checboxes` using `JQuery` and then do further stuff using `ASP.NET`, You could check if the `Checkboxes` are selected using `ASP.NET` insetad of `JQuery`